# Javascript Base64 Render Image

Tags: javascript

Any difference in its implementation?

This doesn't work:

```js
backgroundImage1 = "url('data:image/png;base64,"+data.Items[0][2].Value+"')";
```

but when I change

```js
data.Items[0][2].Value
```

to actual base64 data (value of that item) ,

it properly displays the image in my div background.

What did I miss in the code ?

Comment: Why are you using base64 for this?  Far better would be to keep it as a binary.

Comment: We're going to need better example data than that. What exactly is the value of `data.Items[0][2].Value` at the time you're trying to use it? You could simply put `console.log(data.Items[0][2].Value)` just before your line of code to check

Comment: @Brad plenty of reasons why OP might be using base64 but it's not particularly relevant to this question

Comment: What's the content for data.Items[0][2].Value ?

Comment: @Phil I posted it as a comment, not an answer.  And for what it's worth, out of all of these types of questions I've answered in the last year or more, I haven't seen a single good usage of base64.  I think people forget that browsers can handle binary data, so I always ask.  Usually, it's due to some bad copy/paste code, so I like to help correct it while I answer the question.

Comment: @BryGom the content of it is base64 data.
Portion of it is like below `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAkACQAAD/2wBDABwTFRgVERwYFhgfHRwhKUUtKSYmKVQ8QDJFZFhpZ2JY
YF9ufJ6GbnWWd19giruLlqOpsbOxa4TC0MGszp6usar/2wBDAR0fHykkKVEtLVGqcmByqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqr/wAARCACqAcIDASIA`

Comment: @Brad data returned by the API is in a base64 format.

Comment: @JericJohnRomero _"the content of it is base64 data"_ ~ so is `bW9hciBkZXRhaWxzIHBsZWFzZQ==` but it's not a valid image. How can you expect help if you don't provide details? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61905990/edit)

Comment: @JericJohnRomero you also have to make sure `data.Items[0][2].Value` contains the right value at the time you're trying to use it. You can check this with a simple `console.log()` as mentioned already

Comment: sorry,  too long to put the value here ...

Comment: @JericJohnRomero If you paste whole data string into browser's URL bar with `data:image/png;base64,` prefix, do you see the picture?

Comment: finally figured out the issue, line breaks were added that's why it doesn't render. .

Answer (score -1):

In javascript if you get the value of input then it's display the file path so please find the below code which help you:

```js
function readFile() {

    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

      var FR = new FileReader();

      FR.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = e.target.result;
        document.getElementById("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
      });

      FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }

  }

  document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>A test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50">
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  Display Base64: <p id="b64"></p>
  <br />
  <br />
  Display Image:
  <br /><img id="img" height="150">
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Is there any problem with this solution?